# mollie api bancontact fail

Tags: php, mollie

I am using this code to use the correct payment method.
Except for bancontact it is working, when user opt for bancontact this error is shown `API call failed: Error executing API call (request): The payment method is invalid.`
(Bancontact is set as approved payment option at Mollie)

Any suggestions?
Or what part of code might be interesting to post here to prevent posting to much code.

```
if($_SESSION['checkout_betaling'] == 'iDEAL') { $method = 'ideal'; }
elseif($_SESSION['checkout_betaling'] == 'Bancontact') { $method = 'bancontact'; }
elseif($_SESSION['checkout_betaling'] == 'PayPal') { $method = 'paypal'; }
elseif($_SESSION['checkout_betaling'] == 'SOFORT') { $method = 'sofort'; }
elseif($_SESSION['checkout_betaling'] == 'Belfius') { $method = 'belfius'; }
elseif($_SESSION['checkout_betaling'] == 'KBC / CBC') { $method = 'kbc'; }
elseif($_SESSION['checkout_betaling'] == 'ING HomePay') { $method = 'inghomepay'; }
elseif($_SESSION['checkout_betaling'] == 'Creditcard') { $method = 'creditcard'; }
```

url: `mollie.php?bestel_id=$bestel_id&ordernr=$ordernr&bedrag=$bedrag&method=$method&levertijd_dagen=$levertijd_dagen`

```
$payment = $mollie->payments->create(array(
    "amount"       => "{$bedrag}",
    "description"  => $config['bedrijf']." Bestelling {$ordernr}",
    "redirectUrl"  => "{$protocol}://{$hostname}{$path}/checkout_complete.php?",
    "webhookUrl"   => "{$protocol}://{$hostname}{$path}/mollie_update_db.php",
    "method"       => "{$method}",
    "metadata"     => array(
        "bestel_id" => $bestel_id,
        "ordernr" => $ordernr,
        "levertijd_dagen" => $levertijd_dagen
    ),
));
```

Comment: a long shot [no Bancontact Payments using the v1 branch of the API Client - use mistercash](https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-php/issues/187) - hope that helps

Comment: An long shot right into the target @lovelace :)

Comment: happy to help, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help of lovelace I was able to solve this problem with: [Payment method mistercash should be bancontact · Issue #187 · mollie/mollie-api-php · GitHub](https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-php/issues/187)